# Render Animation error, Blender seems to be trying to render/save to a drive letter that does not exist on my PC

Tags: rendering, error

This is the error I get when I try to render animation:

Render error (No such file or directory) cannot save: 'F:\3dProject(etc. etc.)\001.png'

The thing is I do not have an F:\ drive on my PC?

This does not happen when I render image.

I'm pretty new to Blender. I am using a .blend file that is a character model I downloaded to use, created by someone else. I have a few other character models (.blend files) and they work perfectly fine when rendering the animation. It seems like this file has some kind of default save path based on the creator's file structure/drive maybe? I've tried editing the file path locations in User Preferences to no avail.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this?

Comment: You can see the default output file path in the output properties (the printer icon) under the output subpanel. Alternatively if there is a compositor node tree, it's possible there are output nodes set to write to custom file paths

Comment: Also, check preferences -> File Paths -> Render